# SELECT from two tables based on the same id and grouped

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with different structure (table1 confirmed items, table2 items waiting for confirmation, each user may have more items in either table):

```
table1
id (primary) | user_id | group_id | name | description | active_from | active_to
```

and

```
table2
id (primary) | user_id | group_id | name | description | active_from
```

What I try to have is the list of all the items of a certain user - i.e. rows from both tables with the same `user_id` (e.g. 1) prepared to be shown grouped by `group_id` (i.e. first group 1, then group 2 etc.) ordered by `name` (inside each group). Output should look like that:

```
(all the groups below belong to the same user - with certain user_id)

# Group 1 (group_id) #
Item 67 (id): Apple (name), healthy fruit (description) (item stored in table1)
Item 29: Pear, rounded fruit (item stored in table2)

# Group 2 #
Item 14: Grape, juicy fruit (item stored in table2)

# Group 3 #
Item 116: Blackberry, shining fruit (item stored in table2)
Item 14: Plum, blue fruit (item stored in table1)
Item 7: Raspberry, red fruit (item stored in table1)
```

I am not able to have a working solution, I tried using `JOIN` as well as simple `SELECT` from two tables using `WHERE` clause.

I ended with the following code which is obviously not working since returning wrong (much higher - redundant) number of results (not talking about non-implemented ordering of the results from `table2`):

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.user_id, table1.group_id, table1.active_from, table1.active_to, table2.id, table2.user_id, table2.group_id, table2.active_from
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.user_id = table2.user_id
WHERE (table1.group_id='".$group_id."' OR table2.group_id='".$group_id."') AND (table1.user_id='".$user_id."' OR table2.user_id='".$user_id."')
ORDER BY table1.property_name ASC
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result out of it.

Comment: Could you make an SQL-fiddle with some sample data so we can test this + also the expected output would be nice..

Comment: I agree with the others: Show sample data and expected output. You say both tables are about items. So what is the item's key? The name? Or the group_id? What are the tables' natural keys (i.e. what besides the technical id is unique in the table)? user_id + group_id?

Comment: Sample output added above. To Thorsten: Item's key in table1 is id, in table2 is id as mentioned above (there is no single primary key for both tables). Nor other rows neither their combination may be considered unique.

Comment: Okay, I see. I've added an answer. On a quick glance, the database design doesn't look great by the way. (For instance: this seems to be a user - fruit relation, but there is only a user table we link to, no fruit table. This may be on purpose, but it looks suspicious.) Tell us, if you want help on this.

Comment: Fruits are in the sample as an example only. In fact there is an unlimited amount of items which we do not know in advance (inserted by user). Therefore the fruit table cannot exist in our database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `union` would suit your problem.  Some data massage is required to give both sides of the union the same number and type of columns:

```
select  group_id
,       id as item_id
,       name
,       description
,       source_table
from    (
        select  id
        ,       user_id
        ,       group_id
        ,       name
        ,       description
        ,       'from table1' source_table
        from    table1
        union all
        select  id
        ,       user_id
        ,       group_id
        ,       name
        ,       description
        ,       'from table2'  -- Column name is already defined above
        from    table2
        ) as SubQueriesMustBeNamed
where   user_id = 1
order by
        group_id
,       name
```

[Working example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89d84/4/0)

To format the result set as you like, iterate over the result set.  When the `group_id` changes, print a `# Group N #` header.

There should be no need to have other loops or iterations client-side, just one `foreach` or equivalent over the set of rows returned by the query.

Comment: This helped me to construct part of the correct code using `UNION ALL` and fake columns. In the output code, however, I need to know which item is from which table. How to achieve that?

Comment: The example includes a `source_table` column that you can use to tell which table a row is from

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Just for completion, what way would you advise to display groups in the most efficient way ("You can then create a group for each group_id, and display aggregates for them")?

Comment: The `group by group_id` part of the SQL example implements "create a group for each group_id" ;)  An example aggregate is `count()` or `max()`

Comment: Does that help me in listing the results in the form stated in the sample? (I don't need aggregates there.) Curently, I list the results per group by having first loop listing all the groups of that user and second (inner loop inside each group) listing items in that group. My question was if that can be done in some more elegant way.

Comment: Since I encountered problems in viewing the results of the query (which is otherwise ok and answering the original question), I asked [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29826268/2788840) as how to design the output of the query while meeting several specific requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from a t1 , b t2 where t1.user_id=t2.user_id and t1.group_id='' ORDER BY t1.name ASC
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, from what you say in your comments section I gather that the two tables are not related. So we don't want to JOIN them.

You want to get results of the union of the two data sets (i.e. the two tables, or more precisely: the user's records of the two tables). So use UNION, or better: UNION ALL, (as Andomar already suggested).

You don't want any GROUP BY, because GROUP BY in SQL means to aggregate data (i.e. get one result line per group). You want to ORDER BY group_id instead:

```
select *
from
(
  select group_id, id, name, description, 'confirmed' as status 
  from table1 where user_id = 12345
  union all
  select group_id, id, name, description, 'unconfirmed' as status
  from table2 where user_id = 12345
)
order by group_id;
```

Comment: The code above returns an error `Every derived table must have its own alias`.

Comment: Could you explain use of `'confirmed'`, `'unconfirmed'` and `status`?