# View SELECTion from multiple tables grouped in jquery UI accordion widget

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I would like to use accordion widget (http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) to show the result from the SQL query specified in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29387167/2788840).

I encountered the following problems:

1. the result from SQL does not specify the end of one group and start of another (so I cannot tell accordion to start with a new header);
2. there may be groups which are empty (the list of groups is contained in the third table named `groups` - see its structure below) - user can create a group which can be empty (without items), that group shall be also listed in the result;
3. there is one group common for all the user (group_id 0, group_name General). The group shall be viewed in the list if there is some item owned by the user whose items are listed in the view;
4. in each header of accordion, the name of the group shall be stated (and not the group_id). The group names are contained in the table `groups`. The view shall be sorted according to the group names (and not group_id as in the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29387167/2788840))

Structure of the table `groups`:

```
group_id (primary) | user_id | group_name
```

One user may have zero or more groups. One group is owned just by one user. Only exception is group_id 0 which is common for all the users.

Output should look like that:

```
(all the groups below belong to the same user - with certain user_id, except for group_id 0)

# A group (group_name) (group_id 13) #
Item 67 (id): Apple (name), healthy fruit (description) (item stored in table1)
Item 29: Pear, rounded fruit (item stored in table2)

# B group (group_name) (group_id 4) #
Item 14: Grape, juicy fruit (item stored in table2)

# C group (group_name) (group_id 18) #
Item 116: Blackberry, shining fruit (item stored in table2)
Item 14: Plum, blue fruit (item stored in table1)
Item 7: Raspberry, red fruit (item stored in table1)

# General (group_name) (group_id 0) #
Item 206: General fruit, mysterious fruit (item stored in table1)
```

Comment: You might need nested queries. Have you considered using that ?

Comment: @Maximus2012: I am quite unexperienced in such complex queries. Could you give me a hint, please?

Comment: A general idea would be like this: query1 to get unique groups, as you are iterating through the results of query1, write query2 to get the item information for each item in that group. You might need to customize this and research for more information based on your specific case.

Comment: Well, your suggestion is too much general. Somebody has a more specific hint? Does not need to directly provide an answer as regards the accordion widget. It would be sufficient to help with at least of some of the issues 1 to 4 listed in the original question.